# Having trouble editing the text under label appearance

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am having trouble editing the text of my labels. Usually I go to label > label appearance > text and type what I want the label to say, but Tableau is not letting me. I can also select different alignment features, but when I click on them, they never change the appearance of the text. Does anyone know why I am having this error? If it helps, I am working with one row of pie charts that has around 10 columns.

---

[image]

I was hoping that I would be able to use the alignment feature or something similar to move the percentage symbols around without manually moving them but these features haven't been impacting the text at all when I select them. I would like the 100% in March, April, May, and December to appear outside of the pie chart rather than inside. However, I do not really want to do this manually because in my real data set, I have many more pie charts (over 50). These 50 pie charts will also change over time as the data refreshes, so I would need to manually move them again and again.

Comment: why don't you add some image in order to get a better understanding of your scenario?

Comment: Does this example make sense? @Fabio Fantoni

Comment: in pie charts, you don't have direct control on label positioning just because it's variable according to your data